# How to create a method to calculate minutes per mile in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

In my Rails 4.2.6 / Ruby 2.2.4 project, I have a cardio exercise model with duration, distance and average pace fields.  "Duration" and "average pace" are time datatypes; "distance" is a decimal datatype.  I need help writing a method to calculate a user's average pace (minutes per mile) based on a user's inputs in the duration and distance fields.

*** EDIT ***

The duration and distance fields in my cardio exercises form (_form.html.erb):

```
  <div class="cardio_duration">
    <%= f.input :duration do %> <br>   
    <%= f.time_select :duration, :include_blank => true, include_seconds: true %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="cardio-time"> 
    <%= f.input :distance, :include_blank => true %>
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

Here's what I have coded so far in my cardio exercise model:

```
before_save { self.average_pace = self.calculate_average_pace } # calls calculate average pace method
```

I understand that when calculating minutes per mile, the time factor is on top in the equation.  Here's the method I've written:

```
def calculate_average_pace
    duration = self.duration
    distance = self.distance
    average_pace = duration / distance
end
```

When I execute this method, it generates the following error:

```
undefined method `/' for 2000-01-01 16:50:00 UTC:Time
```

I'm trying to do something like this:  26 minutes / 1.17 miles, which equals 22.29 minutes per mile.  How should I change my code to fix the problem?  Thanks for the help & explanation.

**EDIT **

This is the relevant DB schema:

```
  create_table "cardio_exercises", force: :cascade do |t|
    ...
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.time     "duration"
    t.decimal  "distance"
    t.time     "average_pace"
  end
```

Comment: i think you should refactor your code so `time` is a "number of seconds elapsed" rather than an actual time object. It'll be easier to use math that way.

Comment: How do I convert the time object to "number of seconds "elapsed"? How should I modify my code?

Comment: you're not showing the part of your code where you define `time`. Think about it logically though. If `time` was just a single point in time (something like `Time.now`), how would you know how long the action takes?

Comment: See edit of original post for "time" & "duration" fields on cardio exercise form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting undefined_method error because you're trying to divide `Time` by `Decimal`. Only Numeric values can be divided.

I tried to achive that functionality like this.

```
# _form.html
# ...
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :duration %><br>
    <%= f.time_select :duration, include_blank: false, include_seconds: true %>
  </div>
# ...

# Cardio model
class Cardio < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_mpm

  def set_mpm
    # find minutes from time entered by user
    mins = duration.hour * 60 + duration.min + duration.sec / 60
    self.mpm = mins / distance
  end
end

# controller
  def create
    @cardio = Cardio.new(cardio_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cardio.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cardio, notice: 'Cardio was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @cardio }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @cardio.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is the result

[image: Result]

Is that works for you?

**UPDATE**

1 hour for 10 miles works for me.

[image: Result2]

Here is my DB schema.

```
  create_table "cardios", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.time     "duration"
    t.decimal  "distance"
    t.decimal  "mpm"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Comment: Tried it with a duration set at "01:00:00" and distance set at 10.00 miles, but got the folllowing error:  PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat ERROR: invalid input syntax for type time: "6.0"

Comment: @codeinspired your example works for me. I assume we have differ DB scemas.

Comment: I added my relevant DB schema.  My average_pace attribute is a time datatype.  Your "mpm" is a decimal datatype.

Comment: Got it working!  I ran a db migration to change the datatype of "average_pace" to decimal.  The method works as expected now.  Thank you for all your help!